# What's the difference between using show segue and using navigation controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I am new to iOS development. I found that instead of using navigation controller, I can simply wire a button with the "show" segue and use unwind segue to implement a simple movement between two views. On the other hand, I also know that it is possible to use navigation controller for this purpose.

What's the difference between these two ways? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Navigation Controller Vs Segue is not a good comparison.

Even with Navigation Controller you could use `Segue`.

Using `Segue` is more of an automatic with less programming way of transitioning from VC1 to VC2. There is another traditional and more programmatic way of pushing VC2 on to VC1.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```